# Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'T' and 'T'. in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I am very new to TypeScript. My TypeScript version is 3.7.5.

IMHO, it should be very easy, but I don't know why it does not work.

```
function add<T> (a:T, b:T):T  {
    return a + b ;
}

console.log(add (5, 6));
```

I get the error:

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'T' and 'T'.

I used this one also:

```
function add<T extends string | number > (a:T, b:T):T
```

The same error is there. If I can not use `+` for this generic, why should I use *generics*?

Comment: The question is not why can't you use + for generics, the question is why would you perform arithmetics on anything but a number?

Comment: @AliHabibzadeh arithmetic or string concatenation. You could easily have an operation similar to `["a", "b", "c"].reduce(add)` where you take two strings at a time and pass them through a binary function.

Comment: You never need to add or subtract strings. You need to use string interpolation, .concat, etc.. Math operations are not for strings. If you use them for strings, you are coding wrong.

Answer (score 17):

Generics are not the right approach here. You cannot apply the `+` operator to an unconstrained `T` (why should this work?).

`function add<T extends string | number > (a:T, b:T):T` won't work either, because TypeScript requires at least one operand to be `string`, which is not the case here. E.g., what about this constellation:

```
const sn1 = 3 as number | string
const sn2 = "dslf" as number | string
add(sn1, sn2) // Both types have type number | string, sh*t...
```

The `+` operator cannot be overloaded, but we can still leverage [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) in TypeScript:

```
function add(a: string, b: string): string
function add(a: number, b: number): number
function add(a: any, b: any) {
    return a + b;
}

add(1, 2) // Number
add("foo", "bar") // String
```

Comment: why you think JS allows overload?

Comment: I meant [TS function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads), gonna update.

Comment: `why should this work?` - can you explain why it should not?

Comment: @SET the compiler doesn't know anything about `T`, which in this case gets `unknown` as upper-bound type. So from TS perspective, this is likely to be an error.

Comment: And if they use ES6? Arrow function?

Answer (score 8):

**These are quite common solutions:**

Union addition

```
function add<T extends string | number>(a: T, b: T): T extends string ? string : number  {
  return  <any>a + <any>b; // Cast to any as unions cannot be added, still have proper typings applied
}

const res1 = add(5, 6) // number
const res2 = add('a', 'b') // string
const res3 = add(5, 'b') // Argument of type '"b"' is not assignable to parameter of type '5'.
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoDwBVEFMAeUuYqAzoqVAE4xgDmiAPomCALYBGuVAfABTIAXIiwAaRB2FYAlFLyFiZCtVoMA-Mpr1Ew1p26JEAbwCwAKENVcUEFSSIMyMAE8eyRAGoHT1xwDc5gC%205uYQCJSIVqQAjIgAvCjofACs4gBs0ogA9Fks7FxUoeFQkbikAEzxiah8AOTIteK1HLWZOZqqRWARUQDMVWg1qYjNrdm5AIJUdOzEJXDAiFDOAA64IwBEHBu1iDDkYHAlyKSkMHRgyBwANutQcIgryFTIbNYGC0ur67XJtQB0ITMQA)

---

---

TypeScript function overloading

```
function add(a: string, b: string): string
function add(a: number, b: number): number
function add(a: any, b: any): string | number {
  return a + b;
}

const res1 = add(1, 2); // Number
const res2 = add('a', 'b'); // String
const res3 = add(1, 'b'); // Overload 1 of 2, '(a: string, b: string): string', gave the following error.
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoBTIFyIM5QBOMYA5gDSIBGuBxZAlLUSaYgLABQoksCK6LLjAgAtlQCmhSjUQjxUpnLGTCXHtHhI0mHCjABPGbmSGldVogA%20yhYUQBvLokSEJUEIW2IA1NQDcXAC%20XFwQCASuEngAjIgAvAKYMZQATAyBnOFgkW54qQlJGADkyMWUxVTFGWERUFF4AMyFOhgpiJXV-ogA9D2IAPIAblIANnBoiHFwwIipFUL4LGTGS-Sk5suk5YikyCOIUAAWEojAcKPjAO6WUoRwhAB0XEA)

Comment: indeed, why not to solve any TS-related problem with `any`

Comment: This answer is currently under discussion on [the meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403191).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it is necessary to set constraints like this:

```
add<T extends number> (a:T, b:T):number {
    return a + b;
}
```

or `T` of `string`:

```
add<T extends string> (a:T, b:T):string {
    return a + b;
}
```

This version is not eligible, as whether you get concatenation or addition is not predictable.

```
add<T extends string | number > (a:T, b:T):T {

}
```

Comment: A more general approach might be to create an interface with an `add: (other: T) => T;` member and use that as the constraint.  Would be nice if we could overload operators!!

Comment: if I define both of them I get this:
Duplicate function implementation.

if I want to define only one why should I go for T I can simply define with number
```
function add (a:number, b: number):number  {
    return a + b ;
}

console.log(add (5,6));
```

Comment: @HesamA yeah, you are right, you can simple define as `add (a:number, b: number):number { return a + b ; }`

Comment: "This version is not eligible as whether you get concatenation or addition is not predictable." Should it matter? I'm quite interested in why this version doesn't work, the constraints seem satisfied, and if the signature is satisfied then weather its concat or addition is an implementation detail, no different than T extending IHasAdd and the non-operator add operation for number doing addition and for string doing concat.

Comment: @MâttFrëëman `T extends string | number then T can be string | number` means one value of type `T` can be string and another value of type `T` can be a `number`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be using the same type T for both? How else would you constrain two types to be the same using generics? This does seem like a compiler bug IMO. In fact, the compiler definitely knows / expects them to be the same, which is why it refuses to compile add('s', 5)

Answer (score 0):

There are great answers here. but wanted to show what would be the practical way this can happen and TS would not able to infer the types.

```
function sum<T extends number|string>(a:T,b:T){
   return a+b;
} 

function getNumberOrString(){
  if(Math.random()<0.5){
    return "5";
  }else{
    return 6;
 }
}


let k =getNumberOrString();
let k1 =getNumberOrString();

//type safety issue as k can be number and k1 can be string
console.log(sum(k,k1));
```

Answer (score -2):

specify the type of T, and then use T as a variable to limit the types of x and y

```
function addString<T extends string>(x: T, y: T): string {
  return x + y;
}

function addNum<T extends number>(x: T, y: T): number {
  let a = x * y;
  let b = x - y;
  let z = x++;
  return x + y;
}

addString("a", "b");
addNum(1, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Consider adding an explanation to your code, since that will be more helpful.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. You can [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65282766/edit) (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).