# why TypeScript generic constrain with union (string | number) gives error

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-constraints

if T is string then concatenate  two string.

if T is number then sum two numbers.

Why TSC gives that error?

```
const sum = <T extends string | number>(a: T, b: T): T=> {
  return a + b; // error in here
};
```

**error**: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'T' and 'T'.ts(2365)

Note: a and b must be same exact type. for example

```
const sum = <T extends number[] | string>(a: T, b: T): number => {
  return a.length + b.length;
};

sum("mustafa", "mustafa");
sum([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]);
sum("mustafa", [1, 2, 3]); // error1
sum( [1, 2, 3], 'mustafa'); // error2
```

**error1** : Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '"mustafa"'.ts(2345)

**error2** : Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '"mustafa"'.ts(2345)

Comment: Short answer: because (a) can be a number and (b) string

Comment: I tried some code and realized that "union type definition" and "generic type constraint with union" works different. in my example type T can be one of string or number at same time. So a and b can be string or number not combination of them

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802954/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-types-t-and-t-in-typescript