# How to restrict the generic T of add (a: T, b: T):T in typescript so that it is either a and b are strings, or a and b are numbers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Functions can be defined in js as follows:

`function add(a, b) {return a+b}`

Then it is **allowed** to call as follows:

`add(1, 2)`

`add('hello', 'world')`

However, it is **not allowed** to call:

`add(1, 'world')`

`add('hello', 2)`

The following code cannot meet the above requirements:

`function(a:string|number, b:string|number):string|number {return a+b}`

**How to implement the same code in typescript ?**

Comment: what have you done to try this with generics?

Comment: You'd likely be better off with [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Function Overloads can do it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you post an answer with overloads?

Comment: What I'm interested in is, is there a better implementation of generics?

Comment: Does [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802954/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-types-t-and-t-in-typescript) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

I find this question interesting because this might be a legitimate limitation of TypeScript.

The obvious solution of simply returning `a + b` does not work, TypeScript complains that `T + T` can not be operated on despite what that we know `a` and `b` must be either string or number and both those types are valid in a concatenation or addition operation.

Thus, I bring you, without any casting, a solution to this problem:

```
function add<T extends string | number>(a: T, b: T): T {
  return Array.from(arguments).reduce((t, c) => t + c);
}

console.log(add("Hello", " World!")); // "Hello World!"
console.log(add(4, 3)); // 7
add("Foo", 1337); // Error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoDwBVEFMAeUuYqAzoqVAE4xgDmiAPomCALYBGuVAfABTIAXIiwAaRB2FYAlFMQBvAFCJEVXFBBUkAQSpVkATwB0wKnDYCqddsSilpRtahARcfPlHERpiALw9EKEQAakRvAG5FAF9FRQgEUjgAG1wjJLg6AXQ+ACIACVwk9JzxHMQAdTgqJNQAQhzpaXDEAHoWxHzC9Iqqmvq4hOTU9My0VD4AFnEAZkbmtsQAdkUx3IAxODgSxABGaenFptb2gFE9KqA)

It should be noted this is a sort of hack, `arguments` produces `any[]` and is only available in non arrow functions.

Comment: How is this a limitation of TypeScript? The same could be said for any language that has generics/overloading then. It's reasonable as well. What if `a` is a string and `b` is a number, or the other way around? You get unexpected behavior. Also, this only works because `Array.from(arguments)` produces `any[]`, which should be mentioned.

Comment: It is a limitation and could potentially be added to the compiler (although unlikely). It's still a limitation if it applies to other languages with generics. TypeScript has a more comprehensive compiler however with things like type guards and conditional types, therefore I see this as something that could be added to the language.

Comment: "What if a is a string and b is a number, or the other way around" that's the point, they can't be since they share the same generic. From a compiler perspective it makes sense since TypeScript doesn't do the extra step of checking whether the operands (a and b) have to be the same type and are not just both `string | number`. That's what I find intriguing, that extra step could be added to the language hence why I called it a limitation.

Comment: `Argument of type '1337' is not assignable to parameter of type '"Foo"'. (2345)` is not super helpful to the consumer!

Comment: it's "Foo" since it was supplied a literal, if it was a string it would say "Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'"

Comment: What do you mean? If `T` is a `string | number`, that means `a` and `b` could be either `string` or `number` at runtime. You're effectively adding two things that you don't know the type of for sure at runtime. It may be safe and sound, but this behavior is best prevented...

Comment: This does indeed satisfy the requirement!  `Array.from(arguments).reduce((t, c) => t + c)`, it's just that the types of `t` and `c` here have become `any`, , and the versatility has been reduced, because consumer cannot obtain the methods in `c`, for example: if `c` is `string`, typescript cannot prompt `c.length` . It seems that the current use `Function Overloads` is universal.

Comment: "*I bring you, without any casting, a solution*" - did you mean "type assertion" when you wrote "casting"? You're right, this is a hack - it works the same as, and is as bad as, `return (a as any) + (b as any)` (or actually worse since it's obfuscated) - this is not a solution.

Comment: Btw `add<string|number>("Foo", 1337)` is accepted and does not cause a compile error, so this does not work like the OP expects.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe for the tip, using `Function Overloads`; also thanks to @Undo for his answer.
Below is my typescript code implemented using `Function Overloads`:

```js
function add(a: number, b: number): number
function add(a: string, b: string): string
function add(a: any, b: any): any {
    if (typeof a === 'number' && typeof b === 'number') {
        return a + b // a and b have full type hints, for example: `a.toFixed`
    }
    if (typeof a === 'string' && typeof b === 'string') {
        return a + b // a and b have full type hints, for example: `a.length` .
    }
    throw new Error('the types of a and b must be the same!')
}
```

```js
console.log(add(1, 2)) //OK, 3
console.log(add('hello', 'world')) //OK, helloworld
add(1, 'world') // Error
```

Comment: The actual implementation can be simplified. Just replace your string | number with any and return a + b instead of your complicated if-based control follow.

Comment: @wiktor-zychla  Updated, replace `string | number` with `any`. In the current example it is indeed possible to return `a+b` directly. But in my actual code, I also need to access the methods in `a` and `b`, so I added  if-based control follow.