# In Typescript how can I write a curried function that restricts and infers the output type from the first argument?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm relatively new to Typescript and was wondering: for simple curried function like:

```
const add = (a:number) => (b:number):number => a + b;
```

Is it possible to instead support both number and string input and restrict the output type to the first input type?

E.g.

```
const add = (a:number | string) => (b:type of a):type of a => a + b;
```

Comment: Yes, you can use a generic for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but I think you're stuck with type assertions in the *implementation* of the function. But we can be precise with the typing.

At first glance, you'd "just" use a generic type argument ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgEwTAvDAPAFRgUwB5Q5gIQxgCuAtgEY4BOMAPjNHQJZgDmAfABRwAuGJgCUqbjF7UhomeJgBvAFAxVMAPTqYAOl1tKABwA2OSkShwobcLu1KAvgG4lSk7DioYARmduY1TwAmZ1BIEBNtIxBOfiR+ESkREUc1VU0MFDQAdRA6AGsIABp-cigBF1CIcJxI6NiEXi8EwKSU1PT0TJgAMTg2IwglSuramMQGgCI8CYSJgE8Z5I0tTrRe-oggA)):

```
const add = <T extends number | string>(a: T) => (b: T): T => {
    // ...implementation...
};
```

And indeed that works just fine for something like:

```
let a = 1;
let b = 2;
console.log(add(a)(b));
```

**But**, that doesn't work if you use a literal when calling the `add` function:

```
console.log(add(1)(2));
//                 ^−−−−− Error here
```

The problem is that `T` is inferred as being the literal type `1`, not `number`.

You can solve that by widening it with a mapped type:

```
type Widen<T extends number | string> = T extends number ? number : string;

const add = <T extends number | string>(a: T) => (b: Widen<T>): Widen<T> => {
    // ...implementation...
};
```

Now, all of these work:

```
let a = 1;
let b = 2;
console.log(add(a)(b));     // <== Works

console.log(add(1)(2));     // <== Works
console.log(add("x")("y")); // <== Works
```

but these don't, as desired:

```
console.log(add(1)("y")); // <== Error as desired, can't use string for second function arg
console.log(add("x")(2)); // <== Error as desired, can't use number for second function arg
```

So what about the "implementation" I've conveniently left out above? Unfortunately, `a + b` doesn't work, because TypeScript doesn't quite understand that you can reliably apply `+` to those parameters. But you know you can, so you can work around it with a type assertion:

```
return (a as any) + (b as any);
```

I don't like type assertions and avoid then when possible, but I don't know of a way to avoid it with the above.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I actually found another way to make it work, I think, by overloading the function in an interface:

```interface NumberOrString {
  (a: string): (b: string) => string;
  (a: number): (b: number) => number;
}

const addNumberOrString: NumberOrString = (a: any) => (b: any): any => a + b;```

Comment: @Galadre - Yes, overloading is another alternative (kaya3 highlighted that in another answer). Either way, you have the issue of needing to have `any` involved (inside the function). :-| Overloading is great when there are only a couple of options (as with `string | number`). Using a type parameter is great when it needs to be more open.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you need a [generic type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), something like this:

```
const equals = <T,>(x: T) => (y: T) => x === y;
```

The `<T,>` here declares a generic type parameter. The `,` is needed to avoid a syntax ambiguity in files with JSX components, but if you aren't using those then you can drop the comma.

For your example, you want to constrain the type to be `string | number`, so you need an upper bound on the type parameter:

```
const add = <T extends string | number>(x: T) => (y: T) => x + y;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgRwK4EMA2EYF4YB4AqANAHwAUAHgFwz4CU2xMpAntXQzOdljswNwAoAaEiwUAE3HY8+eOShww4zNABOASzABzGAB8YYJAFsARnFVkqNelkYs2NxlwDUMfgKA)

---

An alternative approach, if there's just a few known types you want to use and you don't need full genericity, is to use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```
function add(x: string): (y: string) => string;
function add(x: number): (y: number) => number;
function add(x: string | number) {
    return (y: string | number) => x + y;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoBQA8BciDOUATjGAOYCUeGAnnoSeRYgLwB8BxpZA3AFChIsBCnTY8YEAFsARgFMiVRLQnT5i1h0myF-QdHhI0mXJ0ZlEAH0Tb1zAN59EzxETlQQRJCrPcrNtQVmdkQsRABqRBp+AF8+IA)

---

For your specific example there's a wrinkle, because TypeScript considers it a likely mistake if you write a `+` that could mean either numeric addition or string concatenation depending on the types at runtime. So in these snippets, you'll get an error like *"Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'T' and 'T'"*. Generally this is a good policy because usually you either definitely want addition and not concatenation, or vice versa.

I take it that your function was just meant to be a simple example, and ambiguously adding strings or numbers is out of scope for your question. But see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59802954/12299000) about fixing this error if it does matter.